# Mongo-Scala Driver unique index

Tags: mongodb, scala, mongo-scala-driver

I want to create unique index to a collection using Mongo-Scala Driver. This driver is new and also I am new to Scala. I am not able to create index via both these two methods.

```
collQueries.createIndex(Document("name" -> 1, "unique" -> true))
```

And this:

```
collQueries.createIndex(Document("name" -> 1, "unique" -> true), IndexOptions())
```

Can anyone please help on how to create unique index in Mongo-Scala driver as it is very new and not much information is available.

Answer (score 2):

To create unique index i use this code:

```
collection.createIndexes(
    Seq(
        IndexModel(
            Indexes.ascending("name"),
            IndexOptions().background(false).unique(true)
        )
    )
)
```

I found very useful this [quick documentation tour](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-scala-driver/1.0/getting-started/quick-tour-admin/).

Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

From the official documentation:

> The Indexes class provides static factory methods for all the MongoDB Index key types.
>   Each method returns an instance of the Bson type, which can in turn be used with the createIndex methods.

Via `IndexOptions` you can set uniqueness and other options.

See [here](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-scala-driver/1.0/builders/indexes/), [here](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-scala-driver/1.0/scaladoc/index.html#org.mongodb.scala.model.Indexes$), [here](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-scala-driver/1.0/scaladoc/index.html#org.mongodb.scala.MongoCollection) and [here](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/index.html?com/mongodb/client/model/IndexOptions.html).

Comment: Can you please tell the syntax by how it can be done. I am not able to use IndexOptions.

Comment: collQueries.createIndex(Document("name" -> 1), new IndexOptions().unique(true))
This is not creating any unique index on "name" in the database.

Comment: This is just a shot in the dark, but what happens if you use Indexes.ascending or Indexes.descending instead of constructing the Bson Document yourself?